# Show progress on UserForm without percentage update

Tags: vba, excel

I want to show progress while my program is doing everything it does, to know that it is working and not failed. Problem is, I don't use any index, `For...Next`, `While`, or anything I can use to call my progress-bar update.

The program:

- opens 2 books
- copies a bunch of rows from one to another and
- refreshes all the data/graphics in many other sheets.

As I don't have a loop through all the rows (which was my main reference point for progress-bar), I'm not sure how I can show the progress.

Sorry if I can't be more specific but I'm not sure if I can share any of the code. If you need more information I could try to post some in here.

My progress-bar code is:

```
Public Sub UpdateProgressBar(PctDone As Single)

    With ProgressForm

        ' Update the Caption property of the Frame control.
        .FrameProgress.Caption = Format(PctDone, "0%")

        ' Widen the Label control.
        .LabelProgress.Width = PctDone * (.FrameProgress.Width - 10)

    End With

    ' The DoEvents allows the UserForm to update.
    DoEvents
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateProgressText(txt)

    ProgressText.Caption = txt

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you could just guess roughly where half way through the code is and place `UpdateProgressBar(50)` there, for example

Comment: You could state what part of the code is being processed rather than a % complete bar.... `Opening Book A`, `Updating Chart B`, etc.  Add a listbox to a form and add items to the list as they're processed.

Comment: I think thats a great idea @Darren Bartrup-Cook problem is that while executing, excel becomes so buggy and barely shows the progress form.